# Como puedo obtener mis registros de firebase de 10 en 10?

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo mi base de datos en firebase y quiero que me regrese los datos de 10 en 10 cada que presione un boton. Como puedo hacer esto?? Estoy programando en android studio y soy nuevo em esto de firebase
Desde ya muchas gracias....

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo pero no me regresa ningun dato
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow Marco. Las imágenes de código no son útiles porque no se puede copiar y pegar. Por favor ponlo como texto y podremos reabrir tu pregunta

Answer (score 4):

Lo que intentas hacer se llama paginacion.
Prueba lo siguiente

```
mOffset = 0;
mPageSize = 10;

mOffset += mPageSize;

mQuery = mDatabase.child("TU_PATH_FIREBASE")
   .limitToFirst(mPageSize)
   .startAt(mOffset);
```

En resumen, `mPageSize` indicas cuantos items quieres leer (campo `limitToFirst`)

El `mOffset` te sirve para saber cuantos items ya leiste. Cuando es tu primera lectura, `mOffset` vale 0 y vas a leer del 0 al 9, y en tu segunda lectura, debes aumentar ese valor a 10 (tamaño de la pagina) para que lea del 10 al 19 y asi sucesivamente